# Passing more than one string and retrieving them on another activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I need to pass different strings on the click of each of my four buttons to another activity. But every time I am getting the same string no matter any button i click. Please have a look and help.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.poz;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Button K = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Kids);
        final Button N = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Novice);
        final Button E = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Expert);
        final Button I = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Impossible);
        final Intent activity2 = new Intent (MainActivity.this, PuzzStart.class);
        final Bundle bundle1 = new Bundle();
        final Bundle bundle2 = new Bundle();
        final Bundle bundle3 = new Bundle();
        final Bundle bundle4 = new Bundle();
        bundle1.putString("Kids", "Kids");
        bundle2.putString("Novice", "Novice");
        bundle3.putString("Expert", "Expert");
        bundle4.putString("Impossible", "Impossible");

        K.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
                    {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            activity2.putExtras(bundle1);
            startActivity(activity2);
        }

        });

        N.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) 
                    {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            activity2.putExtras(bundle2);
            startActivity(activity2);
        }

        });

        E.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
                    {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            activity2.putExtras(bundle3);
            startActivity(activity2);
        }

        });

        I.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
                    {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            activity2.putExtras(bundle4);
            startActivity(activity2);
        }

        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

**PuzzStart.java**

```
package com.example.poz;

import com.example.poz.R.string;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class PuzzStart extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.puzzstart);
    String level = null;
    final TextView lev = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.levelbox);
    final Button shuffle = (Button) findViewById (R.id.shuffle);
    Bundle intent = getIntent().getExtras();
    level = intent.getString("Kids");

    if (level==null)
    {
        level = intent.getString("Novice");         
    }
    if (level==null)
    {
        level = intent.getString("Expert");         
    }
    if (level==null)
    {
        level = intent.getString("Impossible");         
    }

    lev.setText(level);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.puzz_start, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Everytime, I am getting the same string in level i.e "Kids". Please tell me the bug and the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Button K = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Kids);
        final Button N = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Novice);
        final Button E = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Expert);
        final Button I = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Impossible);
        final Intent activity2 = new Intent (MainActivity.this, PuzzStart.class);
        final Bundle bundle1 = new Bundle();

        K.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
                    {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            bundle1.putString("selectedText", "Kids");

        }

        });

        N.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) 
                    {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            bundle1.putString("selectedText", "Novice");

        }

        });

        E.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
                    {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            bundle1.putString("selectedText", "Expert");

        }

        });

        I.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
                    {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            bundle1.putString("selectedText", "Impossible");

        }
        activity2.putExtras(bundle1);
        startActivity(activity2);
        });
    }
```

And retrieve as:

```
Bundle intent = getIntent().getExtras();
level = intent.getString("selectedText");
lev.setText(level);
```

This will be optimum solution without repeated code. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Button K = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Kids);
    final Button N = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Novice);
    final Button E = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Expert);
    final Button I = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Impossible);
    final Intent activity2 = new Intent (MainActivity.this, PuzzStart.class);
    final Bundle bundle1 = new Bundle();

    K.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) 
                {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          bundle1.putString("levels", "Kids");
        activity2.putExtras(bundle1);
        startActivity(activity2);
    }

    });

    N.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
                {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        bundle1.putString("levels", "Novice");
        activity2.putExtras(bundle1);
        startActivity(activity2);
    }

    });

    E.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) 
                {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         bundle1.putString("levels", "Expert");
        activity2.putExtras(bundle1);
        startActivity(activity2);
    }

    });

    I.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) 
                {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        bundle1.putString("levels", "Impossible");
        activity2.putExtras(bundle1);
        startActivity(activity2);
    }

    });
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

and then retrieve by

```
level = intent.getString("levels");
lev.setText(level);
```

Answer (score 0):

Put string into the intent as follow in click listener of each button:

```
activity2.putExtra("key", "value");
```

and retrieve as 
`getIntent().getStringExtra("key")`
 in the resulting activity.

Hope this will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use following constants in your first activity.

```
public static final String EXTRA_BUTTON_PRESSED = "EXTRA_BUTTON_PRESSED";
public static final String BUTTON_KIDS = "Kids";
public static final String BUTTON_NOVICE = "Novice";
public static final String BUTTON_EXPERT = "Expert";
public static final String BUTTON_IMPOSSIBLE = "Impossible";
```

Next, you don't need to use multiple bundles. It can be done preparing a new `Bundle` object when the button is pressed.

```
K.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final Intent intent = new Intent (MainActivity.this, PuzzStart.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(EXTRA_BUTTON_PRESSED, BUTTON_KIDS);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Similarly, you can write other button click handlers.

Next, in your second activity, retrieve the value as follows

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String buttonPressed = bundle.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_BUTTON_PRESSED);
// Your conditional logic to check which button was pressed.
```

Using constants from one single place helps if you decide on changing any of the values later.

Hope this helps.